# Write to multiple rows in excel sheet using pandas xlsxwriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, xlsxwriter

I am trying to write values to excel sheet using xlsxwriter.

When trying to write the data to the second row, the data is overwriting to the first row itself. Since i am new to xlsx writer i am unable to figure out where to iterate over.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter


def outputInExcel(valueToExcel):
    with ExcelWriter('pandas.xlsx', mode='A', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        # write operation perform
        valueToExcel.to_excel(writer,startrow=1, header=False)
        worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
        workbook = writer.book
        header_format = workbook.add_format({
            'bold': True,
            'text_wrap': True,
            'valign': 'top',
            'fg_color': '#D7E4BB',
            'border': 1})

        for row_num,col_num,value in enumerate(valueToExcel.columns.values):
            worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)
        writer.save()


file = "Search.xlsx"#image  reference
df = pd.read_excel(file)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    valueToExcel = pd.DataFrame({
        'Manager': [row['Manager']], 'Policy Name': [row['Policy Name']], 'Numbers': [row['Numbers'], 'Source IP': [row['Source']], 'Destination IP': [row['Destination']]
    })
    outputInExcel(valueToExcel)
```

I am expecting a output like this.

[image]

I am getting a output like this.

[image]

Comment: you probably need row variable and add 1 for every new row, like you did with col_num.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code; you override the same row every time and you restart the writer every row, so that is not very efficient. My recommendation is to write the entire dataframe in one go:

```py
writer = ExcelWriter('pandas.xlsx', mode='A', engine='xlsxwriter')
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
workbook = writer.book
header_format = workbook.add_format({
  'bold': True,
  'text_wrap': True,
  'valign': 'top',
  'fg_color': '#D7E4BB',
  'border': 1
})
# write the header separately so you can format it
for col_num, value in enumerate(['Manager', 'Policy Name', 'Numbers', 'Source IP', 'Destination IP']):
  worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)

df = pd.read_excel(file)
# if you only want specific columns
df = df[['Manager', 'Policy Name', 'Numbers', 'Source', 'Destination']]
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name, index=False, header=False, startrow=1)
writer.save()
```

I tried to keep it as much equal to your code as possible, I just removed the loop and moved the code out of the function

Comment: Can you show me with the example that i have taken, since i am adding additional values to the excel it i try to add new header it i will say keyerror not in index @Ruben Helsloot

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I don't see an example in your code